# PHP POST to AWS S3

Tags: php, image, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload

here is my code here:

```
$result = $s3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'       => $bucket,
    'Key'          => 'image.jpg',
    'SourceFile'   => $_FILES['image'],
    'ContentType'  => 'image/jpg',
    'ACL'          => 'public-read',
    'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY'
));
```

as you can see, I want to pass $_FILES['image'] into the `SourceFile` because that is what I want to upload to AWS S3. how can I do this because the error I get is this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Unable to open Array using mode r: fopen() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in

Comment: In the code above you are missing a closing single quote at the end of 'Key'          => 'image.jpg,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_FILES['image']` is an array that contains other information about the file upload. You can see all the keys here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Your file is actually at `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']`.